# Mysqldump error : Couldn't execute 'show table status

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I have a database that I want to export. It has about 6 GB. PhpMyAdmin could not handle it, so after reading a little bit about it I am trying to do it from the console, unsuccessfully. When I run :

```
./mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > /Users/myuser/Documents/mydatabase.sql
```

It gives me this error :

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show table status like 'USDT@002dXVG\_day'': Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)
```

Is someone encountered with the same problem ?

Comment: Someone messed with your data files?

Comment: I did. My database crashed and I restored it from .frm and .ibd files, and maybe it messed up the things a little.

Comment: A little?  So what, DB is still up and running?  Can you stop and start it?

Comment: After I restored it it's working fine. Finally I managed to export it via phpMyAdmin editing the php.ini file.

Comment: What did you have to change?

Answer (score 1):

The database size itself is very big and that seems to be the reason of `lost connection` to mysql server.

You can try the below command which will try to take the backup after increasing the `net_write_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet`

```
mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL net_write_timeout=300; SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1024*1024*1024;"
```

This command will increase the timeout and max_allowed_packet size.
After this, run the below command to take the dump

```
./mysqldump -u root -p mydatabase > /Users/myuser/Documents/mydatabase.sql
```

If you still get error, please provide exact error you are getting in the mysql error logs.

Comment: can you explain `net_write_timeout` more in detail? I never had to change this variable. Thanks

Comment: Please go though the links https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/07/08/mysql-net_write_timeout-vs-wait_timeout-and-protocol-notes/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369376/mysql-what-is-mysqls-wait-timeout-net-read-timeout-and-net-write-timeout-varia

Since your database tables seems very bug in size, mysql  session might be getting terminated within the specified net_write_timeout. So, it is a good idea to increase the session variables like net_write_timeout and net_read_timeout (based on scenarios). If you still need any help, please let me know.